# Form Validation still submitting empty form

Tags: html, validation

I have a form for user to fill in every field. The situation is, I have an input field that user will type in the name of person involved in the operation and the name will be listed in a textarea. I use "required" and "disabled" at textarea as I need to capture the data inserted by the user from the input field. But, when I try to submit an empty form, it still send empty value to the database.

```html
<form name="prereport" action="insert_operation.php" method="POST">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <input name="inputtitle" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Insert Operation Title" required>
      <br>
      <div class="input-group">
        <input name="inputname" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Insert Name of Person Going">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" onclick="addtext();">Add +</button>
        </span>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div class="output-group">
        <label for="comment">List of Person Going</label>
        <textarea name="outputname" class="form-control" rows="5" id="comment" required required></textarea>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div class="input-group">
        <input name="inputequip" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Insert Equipment to Bring for Operation">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" onclick="addequip();">Add +</button>
        </span>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div class="output-group">
        <label for="comment">List of equipments for operation</label>
        <textarea name="outputequip" class="form-control" rows="5" id="comment" required disabled></textarea>
      </div>
      <br>
      <br>
      <center>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" id="check">Add</button>
      </center>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

**Picture of the form:**

[image]

Comment: "I use "required" and "disabled" at textarea" — Eh? Are you asking how to make a disabled field submit data?

Comment: i have change disabled to readonly. the reason why I use readonly is to avoid user from editing the textarea. but then, when i submit an empty form, it still insert to the database with no data from textarea.

Comment: Are you using safari ?. Required is not supported in Safari. Also, it is introduced with HTML5, so browser should be HTML5 supporting.

Answer (score 0):

What Quentin is trying to say is dat when a field has the property  "disabled" the field won't be send with the form post.

Try using "readonly" instead of "disabled".

> **Key Differences**
>
> **The Disabled attribute**
>
> Values for disabled form elements are not passed to the processor
>   method. The W3C calls this a successful element.(This works similar to
>   form check boxes that are not checked.) Some browsers may override or
>   provide default styling for disabled form elements. (Gray out or
>   emboss text) Internet Explorer 5.5 is particularly nasty about this.
>   Disabled form elements do not receive focus. Disabled form elements
>   are skipped in tabbing navigation.
>
> **The Read Only Attribute**
>
> Not all form elements have a readonly attribute. Most notable, the
>    ,  , and  elements do not have readonly
>   attributes (although thy both have disabled attributes) Browsers
>   provide no default overridden visual feedback that the form element is
>   read only. (This can be a problem… see below.) Form elements with the
>   readonly attribute set will get passed to the form processor. Read
>   only form elements can receive the focus Read only form elements are
>   included in tabbed navigation.

Comment: i have change disabled to readonly. the reason why I use readonly is to avoid user from editing the textarea. but then, when i submit an empty form, it still insert to the database with no data from textarea.

Comment: Can you post the code you use to insert into the database?